# lint-staged run different commands for different folders

Tags: javascript, typescript, lint-staged

My project folder is setup with two subfoders, `frontend` and `backend` to house codes respectively.

Therefore in the root folder I have:

```
- backend
    - package.json
    - other backend codes
- frontend
    - package.json
    - other frontend codes
- package.json
```

In the root's package.json, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "frontend:lint": "cd ./frontend && npm run lint && cd ..",
    "backend:lint": "cd ./backend && npm run lint && cd .."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "10.5.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "frontend/**/*.{ts, tsx, json, html}": [
      "npm run frontend:lint"
    ],
    "backend/**/*.{ts, json}": [
      "npm run backend:lint"
    ]
  }
```

However if I do `git add` and the `git commit` on root level, it keeps saying `No staged files match any configured task.`

I have looked into both of the sub package.json and they all worked. I am not sure how to configure lint-staged to filter files.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation of how to target files is given here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged#user-content-filtering-files

It may not be applicable in your case as your config gives multiple file types, but just to flag it as a possibility, there is a “[Lint-staged tasks do not run if a single filetype is specified with curly braces e.g. *.{js}](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/953) ” ticket open on the `lint-staged` repo in which a collaborator comments:

> We use `micromatch` for the globs, and this sounds like an issue in the library.

Perhaps the issue extends further. I also ran into the `No staged files match any configured task.` message and for me adding the `jsx` extension to the config fixed it.

Originally I had:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
```

After amending to the following, it worked fine:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, use [multi-package monorepo](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#how-to-use-lint-staged-in-a-multi-package-monorepo)

```
root
┣ backend
┃ ┣ .lintstagedrc.json
┗ frontend
┃ ┣ .lintstagedrc.json
┃
```

First, install dependencies in `root/package.json` file, and remove `lint-staged` config field:

```
"husky": "8.0.3",
"lint-staged": "13.2.3"
```

Then, in `.husky/pre-commit` file: (Note: Reinstall package when modify this file.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

In `backend/.lintstagedrc.json` file:

```
{ "src/**/*.{ts,js}": ["eslint --fix", "prettier --write"] }
```

In `frontend/.lintstagedrc.json` file:

```
{
  "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}": [
    "eslint --fix",
    "prettier --write"
  ]
}
```